# Есть ли в Twitter bootstrap кроссбраузерность?

Tags: twitter, bootstrap

Скажите, в `Twitter bootstrap` все-таки нет кроссбраузерности? Или это у меня только нет?

Comment: > Originally built with only modern browsers in mind, Bootstrap has evolved to include support for all major browsers (even IE7!) and, with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones, too.

Не знаю, правда, насколько эти обещания соотносятся с действительностью. О какой, кстати говоря, "некроссбраузерности" у вас идет речь?

Comment: да просмотрел странички в разных браузерах, самое большое отличие от всех это у сафари и IE(немного). В сафари вообще каке-то отступы появляются непонятные в ихнем фиксед-меню. кстати стандартный режим совместимости в IE как это понять ? просто при вкличении его вся верстка едет к чертям, или его вообще не стоит выбирать ?

Answer (score 1):

> Или это у меня только нет?

В bootstrap'е есть кроссбраузерность для тех браузеров, которые пеперчислены в документации к соответствующей версии. Иначе бы им никто не пользовался.

> кстати стандартный режим совместимости в IE как это понять ?

Стандартный режим - эм.. ну это страндартный режим под соответствующий браузер. Можно потребовать его, указав в соответствующем теге новер версии.
Режим совместимости - это глючное создание, где-то между IE7 и IE8. Обычно срабатывает для корпоративных сетей. Можно потреботвать его явно при помощи мета-тега.
Quirks 5 mode (в IE10- просто quirks mode) - эмуляция IE 5.5. Жесть, но в целом работает... Просто там не разгуляешься. Срабатывает если нет doctype или doctype не в первой строке. Можно потребовать явно, указав в мета-теге значение 5.
Quirks mode в IE11 - что-то хитрое - то, что должно работать, как предписывает стандарт для почти стандартного режима. По идее, это аналог почти стандартного режима других браузеров. Условие не помню.

Советую всегда писать doctype начиная с первого символа докумета и явно указывать edge для версии IE.

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap использует самые современные
> наработки в области CSS и HTML,
> поэтому необходимо быть внимательным
> при поддержке старых браузеров.
> **Wikipedia**

Comment: браузеры новые, постоянно обновляю! сафари с ооф сайта скачан сегодня.

Comment: с 12 оперой у Bootstrapa'а тоже проблемы были из-за того что `oTransitionEnd` переименовали в `otransitionend`, возможно скоро пофиксят

Comment: случайно не знаешь что за отступы в сафари?

Comment: нет, это единственный браузер, в котором я не тестировал `bootstrap`, т.к. он на WebKit'е как и хром

Comment: в хроме все нормально, вот только в сафари проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Есть официальная дока со списком поддерживаемых браузеров - http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/getting-started/#support

Если нашли баг, который не упомянут как known issue в доке - постите в https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues